# Django "Cannot resolve keyword" error. Can someone explain this?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am just begining to learn how to use django. I am comming up with this error in  my CLI

```
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1337,
  in setup_
    "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(names)))
  FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'likes' into field. Choices are: id, name,
  page
```

My problem is that I don't know what it means or how to fix it. Can someone please explain?
This is the output that the debugger log gave me:

```
Error during template rendering

In template C:\Users\aharon\Desktop\TEMP\index.html, error at line 40
Cannot resolve keyword 'likes' into field. Choices are: id, name, page
30  </html>
31  
32  <html>
33      <head>
34          <title>Rango</title>
35      </head>
36  
37      <body>
38          <h1>Rango says...hello world!</h1>
39  
40          {% if categories %} <--this was highlighted in the debugger
41              <ul>
42                  {% for category in categories %}
43                  <li>{{ category.name }}</li>
44                  {% endfor %}
45              </ul>
46          {% else %}
47              <strong>There are no categories present.</strong>
48          {% endif %}
49  
50          <a href="/rango/about/">About</a>
```

View code:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from rango.models import Category

def index(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)

    category_list = Category.objects.order_by('-likes')[:5]
    context_dict = {'categories': category_list}

    return render_to_response('index.html', context_dict, context)
```

Comment: Show us the view's code. The issue is in the `categories` queryset.

Comment: edited and added view code

Comment: And the `Category` model's definition?

Comment: Could you share categories model its seems 'like' is not an attribute in categories model.

Comment: I can't share pics yet but here's the list contains Category:likes, view, Test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is caused by the following line:

```
category_list = Category.objects.order_by('-likes')[:5]
```

It appears that `Category` model has no field `likes`, but `id`, `name` and `page`.

Answer (score 1):

**Your problem  caused in your model LIKES field**

> "likes" field not in your  model. add "likes" field and the run [migration](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about there being a better way but I added likes in models.py so that it looks like this:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0) # I added this line
    def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
```

Next I deleted the database because migrate isn't working for some reason

then:
    python manage.py syncdb

This fixed the likes issue but it also killed all the information from the earlier step in the tutorial where we made the populate_rango.py file. So I then ran that again.

```
python populate_rango.py
```

then my rango page displayed properly.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to **django/models.py**...in class Category

```
likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Then run:

```
$ python manage.py makemmigrations

$ python manage.py migrate..
```

and refresh the browser